# iOS 16.1 breaks UITextView tokenizer for words and sentences?

Tags: ios, uikit

The built-in UITextView tokenizer function `rangeEnclosingPosition(_:with:inDirection:)` seems to have broken in iOS 16.1 for the `word` and `sentence` granularity.

- `word` doesn't seem to ever return a range
- `sentence` only works for the very last sentence in the text view

Is anyone else using the `tokenizer` (`UITextInputTokenizer`) property of `UITextView` to parse sentences, and is there another way?

I'm using it to select a full sentence in one tap.

### Minimal reproduction

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let textView = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        
        textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, asperiores veniam praesentium repellat doloribus ut und. Soluta et hic velit aliquid totam aperiam ipsam ex odio, voluptatem iste saepe sit."
        
        self.view.addSubview(textView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 16),
            textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -16),
            textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])
        
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedLabel(sender:)))
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    @objc func tappedLabel(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.state == .ended else { return }
        
        let location = sender.location(in: textView)
        let textposition = textView.closestPosition(to: location)!
        
        /// This works to grab a text range for a tapped sentence in iOS < 16.1
        /// but returns null in 16.1 for all but the final sentence.
        let expandedRange = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(textposition, with: .sentence, inDirection: .layout(.right))
        
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        textView.selectedTextRange = expandedRange
    }
}
```

Comment: I am currently investing the same issue and reaching the same conclusion. Looks like this is broken on iOS 16.1. Have you filed a report to Apple or found one already filed?

Comment: I've filed as FB11745517. For what it's worth, I wrote a UITextView extension to replace the functionality in my case. Maybe a naive way to do it but it's working well for me: https://gist.github.com/toemat/bbde4032969580fe828e17c05b59b68f

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try to change the inDirection: to UITextWritingDirection.rightToLeft.rawValue
This worked for me (even that it is logically wrong to me). Hope it helps:

```
guard let wordRange = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPos, with: .word, inDirection: UITextDirection(rawValue: UITextWritingDirection.rightToLeft.rawValue) ) else {
        return nil
    }

    return textView.text(in: wordRange)
```